# How can I influence CMake's compiler choice logic?

Tags: cmake, build-automation, build-settings

I'm working on a project using the C++ language (but - this is not a C++-specific question, really). On my system, there are several C++ compilers installed, several versions of the same compiler, and perhaps even some versions built myself under my own home directory. I use different compilers (of C++) for different purposes (although I'm exaggerating here a little to make the question more general).

Now, my project depends, for some reason, on the compiler being gcc rather than clang, and with version between 4.7 and 4.9 with a preference for a newer version.

I want to get CMake to find the relevant compilers I have, and to use the best one available, if there's a valid one. But - I want this to happen not just on my system; that is pretty easy to force. I want it to do this on *any* (reasonable) system, and not depend on the developer who grabs my code doing any customization of CMakeLists.txt or setting the compiler explicitly with `CXX=/some/thing` etc.

More concretely:

- How do I affect the kinds of locations CMake looks for compilers in?
- How do I affect the order in which these locations are searched?
- How can I express preference of certain compiler providers and versions?
- How can I express constraints on the compiler provider and version?

**Notes:**

- Answers which work for CMake 3.x only are relevant, but I'm also interested in CMake 2.8.x .
- You can tell me to RTFM, but please be specific about what FM and where in the FM (and whether it will actually help me).
- I'm working on Linux in case it matters.

Comment: I suspect if CMake searches, it is according to your path. So the order of the paths in $PATH.

Comment: @hiandbaii: But that would be just part of the story. Suppose my path has 3 `g++`s, a `g++-5.2`, `g++-4.6`,  `g++-4.8` and  `g++-4.7` in that order. How can I tell it what to prefer?

Comment: I don't think there's any official way to restrict allowed compilers, but you can certainty write some control statements with CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION

Comment: @hiandbaii: Can I express vesion constraints?

Comment: thats what you use with CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION ?

Answer (score 0):

CMake is using /usr/bin/c++ unless CXX is set or -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER is passed to your CMake call.

You can get the found compiler version from CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER and error out if it is not sufficient. Same is true if you check for specific C++ compiler features like variadic templates.
But I don't know of a way to check several compilers and choose one by CMake.